# An error of Graphing Calculator Desmos?

Tags: soft-question, math-software

Can someone explain to me this error of the Desmos graphic calculator? Why ? For other values of $x$, the exact value of $f(x)$ is obtained.

Or am I wrong when I assure that $f(\sqrt2)=0$?

[image]

Comment: It's doing the best it can.

Comment: "*For other values of $x$, the exact value of $f(x)$ is obtained*"  Oh, really?  I find that hard to believe.  Does it get an exact value when plugging in $\pi$?  Or $e$?  The issue here is that $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number and as such cannot be easily handled by software.  Some software can handle square roots a bit more carefully, but others will just first find an approximation for the root first, which is *not* an exact value for the root, and use that approximation throughout its arithmetic operations, thus having a non-exact answer at the end.

Comment: Even some rational numbers calculators cannot handle properly.  Some are particularly bad about it.  If you've ever tried dividing by $3$ and then multiplying by $3$ with a pocket solar-powered dollar-store calculator, you will know what I mean.

Comment: @J Moravitz: Yes, I agree with your objection. I wanted to say for current values of $x$ in general $f(x)$ is not so flagrantly wrong.

Comment: @J Moravitz: And for " flagrantly wrong" I want to say that the exact value of $f(x)$ is exactly determined by anyone.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all software uses certain limited precision. The value shown is very close to being zero. This non-exact value is always to be expected in machine numerical calculations. It happens either due to the methods used in calculating square root, floating point arithmetic in the computer, truncation errors, and so on. Also, this occurs with numbers such as $\pi$, $\sqrt{2}$, etc. See for example [How to calculate Square Roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots)

In short we can't say its  wrong, its just that your expectations are high.

Update:
It is possible in programming to do something like this:

```
if variable < tinyConstantValue then
{display zero}
else
{display variable value as is}
```

That is to say, we can't tell about how internally the variable value was calculated even though we can see a zero in the result.

A famous reference about floating point in computers is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @JMoravitz, you are correct. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate much the extraordinary work of the creators of mathematical software .What about if you change the value of $a$ in the Desmos's answer $a\times 10^ {-16}$ for other values. Why the particular given value of $a$? Sorry for bad English. Can you expose an example where the correct number corresponds to an integer easily calculated and however it is given by an approximation like that.?

Comment: I have seen other similar examples and also Desmos makes the same mistakes. But, for example, Wolfram gives the exact value $0$. However your answer (and Moravitz's implicit) should be considered correct. I have put you an upvote.

Comment: @Piquito, are you are suggesting that $a=4.44....$ is always used instead of zero? The fact that Wolfram result is zero does not necessarily mean that the calculation is zero. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Desmos is a calculator.  Mathematica is a computer algebra system.

Comment: @Randall this an interesting distinction to think about!